# How to Configure Onelogin as Dummy IdP

Tags: java, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, onelogin

I am a beginner at SSO. I am trying to implement IdP initiated SSO (SAML2.0). As a par tof this project, I am required to configure IBM Websphere as Service Provider (SP). Have configured the it and the TAI (Trust association Interceptor) as per th [IBM Docs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYGQH_5.5.0/admin/secure/t_sec_config_saml_for_tfim.html)

Now, I need a locally set-up IdP which can be used to test if the SP is configured and SSO is working or not. I am thinking of using OneLogin as dummy IdP but am not able to find any instructions on how to configure OneLogin as IdP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a free, open dummy idp at http://stubidp.kentor.se.

*Disclaimer: I'm the author/maintainer of the AuthServices project that the StubIdp is part of*

Comment: Thanks, this helped me resolve the Dummy IdP problem

Comment: found another way for making IdP Stub. One can use OneLogin -> Add Apps -> SAML Test Connector (IDP w custom attirbutes w/t signed Response) and configure its properties according to the SP.